# select to multiply tables for print mysqli_num_rows

Tags: php, mysql

Good evening all.

Is there one that will give me an example of how to make such a script here:

I try to make a while combining 2 different tables in my database to get correct mysqli_num_rows.

Like this:

```
     $Querypris ("SELECT * FROM" wpd2_posts` where post_status = 'wc-failed' and select * From `wpd2_postmeta` where meta_key = '_ order_total' and meta_value> 300 ')
     $Num_rowspris = mysqli_num_rows ($ query price);
```

So I want to get mysqli_num_rows from all those who are post_status = 'wc-completed' but also meta_value> 300

Hope you understand what I mean :)

Comment: Is your site WordPress?

Comment: Please check the spelling of your keywords and variable ids, as well as literal strings. We are serious people here ;)

Answer (score 1):

Well, your php code will not work like this. At least variable names must be consistent.

You should use JOIN clause in your sql statement. I suppose, there is a column like "post_id" in both tables.

```
$query_price = "SELECT * FROM wpd2_posts JOIN wpd2_postmeta USING (post_id) WHERE post_status = 'wc-completed' AND meta_key = '_order_total' AND meta_value > 300";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query_price);  
$number_of_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
```

UPDATE:

If names of the columns, referring to ID of the post, are different in those tables, for example "ID" in "wpd2_posts" and "post_id" in "wpd2_postmeta", then you should use a following query:

```
SELECT * FROM wpd2_posts p JOIN wpd2_postmeta pm  
ON p.ID = pm.post_id
WHERE p.post_status = 'wc-completed' 
AND pm.meta_key = '_order_total' AND pm.meta_value > 300
```

UPDATE: removed space from '_ order_total'. changed to '_order_total'

Comment: In one table is called the ID in the other named the post id

Comment: And thank you for your reply, hope you will give you time to help solve the task

Comment: It works really fine now. But I get only 0 rows. I simply can not understand it if I do it like this: SELECT * FROM wpd2_postmeta where meta_key='order_total' and meta_value > 300 i get 24 rows and when i run this SELECT * FROM `wpd2_posts` where post_status='wc-completed' i get many rows also  many where meta_value is over 300 http://imgur.com/a/xjmEZ and when i take the pris  i run this SELECT meta_value FROM `wpd2_postmeta` where meta_key='_order_total' and post_id='rowID' hope your understand.

Comment: Check the following: "select post_id from wpd2_postmeta where meta_key='_order_total' and meta_value > 300". You get the list of post_id's. Now check if any of these post_id's are also present in table wpd2_posts: "select * from wpd2_posts where ID = X", where X is any of the post_id's from the first query.

Comment: Yes, it seems perfect! Can you tell me what's wrong?

Comment: i don't know, why it does not work, because i don't see the data in those two tables. If you want help, export the data from these 2 tables as csv files and attach these files to your question. maybe than we can see what's wrong.

Comment: Ok, i inserted your data in a test database and checked the query. I could see, that my query is not working, because there is an empty space here: pm.meta_key = '_ order_total' - it's between _ and order_total. So it should be '_order_total' - no space. And i've got 31 results.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * FROM wpd2_posts,wpd2_postmeta where wpd2_posts.post_status = wc-completed and wpd2_postmeta.meta_key = _ order_total and wpd2_postmeta.meta_value > 300 and wpd2_posts.fk=wpd2_postmeta.fk

this thing might not work for not having foreign key

SELECT * FROM wpd2_posts CROSS JOIN wpd2_postmeta where wpd2_posts.post_status = wc-completed and wpd2_postmeta.meta_key = _ order_total and wpd2_postmeta.meta_value > 300

Its better to use foreign keys.
hope this will help

Comment: thanks for reply! I'm sorry for this: ou have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'order_total and wpd2_postmeta.meta_value > 300' at line 1

Comment: Have corrected the mistake .. but i for only 0 rows and i know there are many more rows?

Comment: When i run this way i'm 24 rows : SELECT * FROM `wpd2_postmeta` where meta_key='_order_total' and meta_value > 300  and when i run this ELECT * FROM wpd2_posts,wpd2_postmeta where wpd2_posts.post_status ='wc-completed' and wpd2_postmeta.meta_key ='_ order_total' i get 0 rows.. whats going on ?

Comment: those two tables doesn't have fk .may be thats why you are'nt getting result

Comment: # 1054 - Unknown column 'wpd2_posts.fk' in table where clause

Answer (score 0):

**If your site is WordPress then use this:**

```
global $wpdb;
$sql="SELECT * FROM wpd2_posts pt INNER JOIN wpd2_postmeta pmt ON  pmt.post_id = pt.ID WHERE pt.post_status = 'wc-completed' AND pmt.meta_key = '_order_total' AND pmt.meta_value>300";


$results = $wpdb->get_results($sql, ARRAY_A );
$num_rowspris = count($results);

// OR ---------

$results = $wpdb->query($sql);
$num_rowspris = $results->num_rows;
```

**else :**

Note: $conn is your DB connection

```
$results = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$num_rowspris = mysqli_num_rows($results);
```

Comment: I'm just programming from wordpresses db not inside wp